# Error in split == FALSE : comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types

Tags: r

while i was working  got stuck here , i would appreciate if some one could assist me in resolving the issue, below is the code and error message for your reference.

```
library(caTools)
split_data <- sample.split(filter_data_1$spend, SplitRatio = 0.75)
split_data    
train_data <- subset(filter_data_1, split == TRUE)
test_data <- subset(filter_data_1, split == FALSE)
```

***Error message :***

```
test_data <- subset(filter_data_1, split = = FALSE)
```

***Error:***

> unexpected '=' in "test_data <- subset(filter_data_1, split =="
>   test_data <- subset(filter_data_1, split == FALSE)
>    Error in split == FALSE :
>     comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types

Comment: You've defined `split_data`, but then tried to use `split`. `split` happens to be a base R function, so that's the first object R will find when searching heirarchically for it. The error is telling you that `[function] == [boolean]` doesn't make sense.

Comment: ohh thanks its working .....

Answer (score 1):

This example works for me:

```
library(caTools)
library(MASS)
data(cats)
filter_data_1 <- cats
split_data <- sample.split(filter_data_1$Sex, SplitRatio = 0.75)
split_data    
train_data <- subset(filter_data_1, split_data == TRUE)
test_data <- subset(filter_data_1, split_data == FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

### change split to 'split_data'

`split_data = sample.split(filter_data_1$spend, SplitRatio = 0.75)    train_data = subset(filter_data_1, split_data == TRUE) test_data = subset(filter_data_1, split_data == FALSE)`

because in the first line the data set has already splitted.